# Is there such thing as unstuffed space?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm translating a poem from Bulgarian to English and the poet used a word that roughly translates as unstuffed, i.e. a space that is not empty, but is also not stuffed/crammed. Do you think unstuffed translates this well enough? As it is a poem I cannot translate it with many words.

Comment: You could help us by offering the line from the poem that had this word blanked out like so _____.

Comment: And sometimes offering the complete sentence with the original word that you're trying to translate can be even more helpful.

Comment: Was 'непълнени' the original word? Possibly 'uncongested' or 'open' space... The context would surely help.

Comment: The original word is "ненатъпкани". The whole "sentence" is: each skeleton grows silent, bypassed beds,
stuffed with clothes, someone was dying here,
they never found him, he vanished, like the cold,
he dispersed, like the light,
the space remains unstuffed and everything is hanging in here

Answer (score 1):

How about *[uncluttered](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/uncluttered)*

> Not filled or covered with unnecessary things: not cluttered

Mirriam Webster

Answer (score 0):

> **minimal**
>
> adjective
>
> 1. of a minimum amount, quantity, or degree; negligible.
>      "a minimal amount of information"
>      synonyms:   very little, minimum, the least (possible);
> 2. ART
>      characterized by the use of simple or primary forms or structures, especially geometric or massive ones.
>
> [google.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=minimal&oq=minimal&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Certainly falls between crowded and baren.  May work depending on the rest of the poem.